# Correct way to replace date YYYYMMDD to YYYY-MM-DD by using replace method

Tags: python, replace

What is the best practice to open a text file with Python and replace date from YYYYMMDD to YYYY-MM-DD?

```
.replace('YYYYMMDD','YYYY-MM-DD')
```

- Need to find all numbers 8 digits long (which are in first 20 characters of each line)
- Add dash after 4 digits and after 6

Comment: Please include example(s) of things you have tried. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Add sample input for which you are trying to do this manipulation.

Comment: A few notes. Text files I generally not edited in place. You create a new file and write your data there. Then when you are done you can overwrite your current file. Secondly, if your file has a structure you should use that structure isolate the dates.  If your file has no structure, you will have to fall back on regular expressions to isolate the dates. Convert the date strings to dates and format back to date strings in the proper format. Round tripping to a date type will catch invalid dates well as handling the formatting.

Comment: there is a library called [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#module-datetime) that handles all that complexity for you. and believe me it can get very complex. You just need to convert your input to datetime objects and the rest is simply formating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to replace numbers with the same numbers in a different format:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "Text to replace parts of 20190913 here is the part to replace"
>>> re.sub(r'\s(\d{4})([0-1][0-9])([0-3][0-9])\s', r' \1-\2-\3 ', s)
'Text to replace parts of 2019-09-13 here is the part to replace'
```

#### Explanation:

`\d` captures numbers (digits).
`{n}` marks the number of digits to capture
`\s` captures white spaces, so we don't capture number sequences longer than 8 digits.
`(...)` mark groups, which can be indexed
`[]` sets allow for only certain characters to match, to catch non-dates
So we capture three groups, right after each other, the first with any numbers 4 digit long, and the next to must start with a `0` or `1` and the second must start with between `0` and `3`; and than we use the same groups just separated by `-` characters in the replace part.
The `r''` is used to specify raw string encoding, so the `\` is picked up by regex, and not by Python.

Comment: And suppose the text file includes `Part No 10000088889`. This makes it `Part No 1000-00-88889`.  One improvement here would and to write a better regular expression that only matches 8 digits not preceded or followed by a digit. The second improvement would be only do a replacement when the eight digits represent a valid date.  It would be odd to convert `20196789` to `2019-67-89`.

Answer (score 0):

You open can open a textfile and read the content the following way

```
with open(filePath) as f:
    content = f.read()
```

Then you can reformat all 8 digits numbers to your date format with this:

```
re.sub(r'(\d{4})(\d{2}(\d{2}))', r'\1-\2-\3', content)
```